# How to add xml attributes to partial class generated by entity

Tags: xml, vb.net, entity-framework

I need to import users from xml file. My user class is autogenerated by Entity Framewok 5 and name of propreties of class are differents than names of xml properties. I can't change that.

XML Structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LISTE_EMPLOYES>
  <EMPLOYE>
    <user_unique_key>A0001</user_unique_key>
    <user_job_matricule>001017</user_job_matricule>
    <user_etaciv_nom>DOE</user_etaciv_nom>
    <user_etaciv_prenom>JOHN</user_etaciv_prenom>
    <user_etaciv_genre>M</user_etaciv_genre>
</EMPLOYE>
<EMPLOYE>
    <user_unique_key>A0003</user_unique_key>
    <user_job_matricule>005017</user_job_matricule>
    <user_etaciv_nom>DOE</user_etaciv_nom>
    <user_etaciv_prenom>PAT</user_etaciv_prenom>
    <user_etaciv_genre>F</user_etaciv_genre>
</EMPLOYE>
</LISTE_EMPLOYES>
```

Partial Class autogenerated

```
Partial Public Class User
    Public Property unique_key As String
    Public Property matricule As String
    Public Property nom As String
    Public Property prenom As String
    Public Property genre As String
End Class
```

So is it possible to add xml attributes with similar mechanism of data annotations ?

```
    <MetadataType(GetType(UserMD))> _ Partial Public Class User End Class

Public Class UserMD
    <StringLength(60)> _ Public Property nom As Object

    <StringLength(60)> _ Public Property prenom As Object
End class
```

thanks

Comment: Can you post a sample of the attribute in XML.  An attribute will have an equal sign before the value.  Elements don't have the equal sign.

Answer (score 0):

Try code below.  The class names do not have to match the XML file.  The attributes above definitions will define the XML names.

```css
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Serialization
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Const FILENAME As String = "c:\temp\test.xml"
        Dim employees As New Liste_Employees

        employees.employee = New List(Of Employee)(New Employee() { _
            New Employee With { _
                .user_unique_key = "A0001", _
                .user_job_matricule = "001017", _
                .user_etaciv_nom = "DOE",
                .user_etaciv_prenom = "JOHN",
                .user_etaciv_genre = "M"
            }, _
            New Employee With { _
                .user_unique_key = "A0003", _
                .user_job_matricule = "005017", _
                .user_etaciv_nom = "DOE",
                .user_etaciv_prenom = "PAT",
                .user_etaciv_genre = "F" _
            } _
        })

        Dim serializer As XmlSerializer = New XmlSerializer(GetType(Liste_Employees))

        Dim writer As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(FILENAME)
        serializer.Serialize(writer, employees)
        writer.Flush()
        writer.Close()
        writer.Dispose()

        Dim xs As XmlSerializer = New XmlSerializer(GetType(Liste_Employees))
        Dim reader As XmlTextReader = New XmlTextReader(FILENAME)
        Dim newEmployees As Liste_Employees = CType(xs.Deserialize(reader), Liste_Employees)


    End Sub

End Module

<XmlRoot("LISTE_EMPLOYES")>
Public Class Liste_Employees
    Private m_employee As List(Of Employee)
    <XmlElement("EMPLOYE")>
    Public Property employee As List(Of Employee)
        Get
            Return m_employee
        End Get
        Set(value As List(Of Employee))
            m_employee = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
<XmlRoot("EMPLOYE")>
Public Class Employee
    Private m_user_unique_key As String
    <XmlElement("user_unique_key")>
    Public Property user_unique_key As String
        Get
            Return m_user_unique_key
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_user_unique_key = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private m_user_job_matricule As String
    <XmlElement("user_job_matricule")>
    Public Property user_job_matricule As String
        Get
            Return m_user_job_matricule
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_user_job_matricule = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private m_user_etaciv_nom As String
    <XmlElement("user_etaciv_nom")>
    Public Property user_etaciv_nom As String
        Get
            Return m_user_etaciv_nom
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_user_etaciv_nom = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private m_user_etaciv_prenom As String
    <XmlElement("user_etaciv_prenom")>
    Public Property user_etaciv_prenom As String
        Get
            Return m_user_etaciv_prenom
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_user_etaciv_prenom = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private m_user_etaciv_genre As String
    <XmlElement("user_etaciv_genre")>
    Public Property user_etaciv_genre As String
        Get
            Return m_user_etaciv_genre
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_user_etaciv_genre = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class


​
```

Comment: Thank you but I don't wish to define another class. I need to fill user class with informations from xml file. I want to know if another way exist to map xml attributes to properties of class.

Comment: I don't think I'm adding any additional classes.  Any autogenerated XML in Net Library has each tag in a separate class except for leaf nodes which are group into a single class.  The code I generated exactly matches you  XML file.  Your XML has 3 layers and I have 3 layers of classes.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help. I use "another" solution based on your :

```
    <XmlRoot("LISTE_EMPLOYES")>
    Public Class Liste_Employees
        Private m_employee As List(Of Employee)
        <XmlElement("EMPLOYE")>
        Public Property employee As List(Of Employee)
            Get
                Return m_employee
            End Get
            Set(value As List(Of Employee))
                m_employee = value
            End Set
        End Property
    End Class

    <XmlRoot("EMPLOYE")>
    Public Class Employee
        Private _u as User

    Public Property user_unique_key As String
        Get
            Return _u.unique_key
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _u.unique_key = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property user_job_matricule As String
        Get
            Return _u.matricule
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _u.matricule = value
        End Set
    End Property ...
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, buy my answer is in c# but should be simple enough to adjust for vb.
EF creates you a class as in your example

```
Partial Public Class User
Public Property unique_key As String
Public Property matricule As String
Public Property nom As String
Public Property prenom As String
Public Property genre As String
End Class
```

One way you can do what you want is create a separate file i.e. Partials.cs. In this separate file you can keep your partial class additional information.  For your class above (in c#) you would do something similar to

```
[MetadataType(typeof(UserMetaData))]
[XmlElement("User")]
public partial class User{}

public partial class UserMetaData
{
[XmlElement("user_unique_key")]
public string unique_key;
[XmlElement("user_job_matricule")]
public string matricule;
[XmlElement("user_etaciv_nom")]
public string nom;
[XmlElement("user_etaciv_prenom")]
public string prenom;
[XmlElement("user_etaciv_genre")]
public string genre;
}
```

this basically tells your partial class to get metadata from the UserMetaData class, which you can assign as many attributes to each property as you desire.  Only thing to note is if you add more columns to the table and reimport with EF you will need to add these columns here in the partial class if you want to control the names.

Again sorry for the c#but I don't use vb but should be easy enough for you to convert.

Hope it helps you achieve your goal.

Cheers
Andy